# Get the Digits From a String Before and After Special Character using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string like 
`5|10|20|200|300` 
and i want to get the First Digit Before `|` and last digit after `|` that is 5 and 300.

How would I use regex in javascript to return  that numbers??

Comment: why not using `.split("|")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript only keeps the last capture for `(...)+`, so you can write

```
var m = "5|10|20|200|300".match(/(\d+)(\|(\d+))+/);
```

Then `m[1]` is `"5"` and `m[3]` is `"300"`

Comment: if the expression is |5|10|20 then how could i get 5 from string

Comment: @ShaheerAli `m[1]`, did you try it?

Comment: after some change i get the desired result thanks for help :)

Answer (score 8):

This simplest regex will return the two matches `5` and `300`:

```
^\d+|\d+$
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/6).

In JS:

```
result = yourString.match(/^\d+|\d+$/g);
```

**Explanation**

- `^\d+` matches the beginning of the string and some digits (the `5`)
- OR `|`
- `\d+$` matches some digits and the end of the string

Comment: i want to get the both number separately its return two number

Comment: Yes the numbers are in an array, just get result[0] and result[1]. :)

Comment: if the string is in that format |5|100|200 then how could i get the first digit

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = '5|10|20|200|300';
var array = string.split('|');
 //array[0] = '5';
 //array[array.length-1] = '300';
```

It's not regex I know, but I've always found split easier to work with in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string into an array using split() method

```
var str="5|10|20|200|300";
var res_array = str.split("|");
```

now to get first and last value of an array:::

```
alert("First value is"+ res_array[0]);
alert("Last value is"+ res_array[arr.length - 1]);
```